# How to cross join generate_series and table with Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, cross-join

I would like to cross join a table with a series of data generated by the `generate_series()` function to generate 36 month.

I don't know how to make a cross join that works with this configuration.

Knowing that:

- I can't create a new table to store the result of the generate_series()
- And using Redshift I don't have a recent version of PostgreSQL I'm forced to make my `generated_series()` like this for it to work.

I have tried this without success.

```sql
WITH sales AS (
SELECT 
   department
  ,product
  ,count(*) as invoice 

FROM table 
  WHERE  product SIMILAR TO '%(Apple|Lemon|Salt)%' 
  AND department is not NULL 
  group by department , product order by department , product ASC
),


date_gen as( SELECT (date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE::TIMESTAMP))  - (i * interval '1 month') as date_datetime 
FROM generate_series(1,36) i 
)

SELECT * FROM date_gen
CROSS JOIN sales;
```

If you have pro tips :)

Comment: My past experiments show that `generate_series()` operates on the Leader node, so it cannot be joined with data from tables. You could use `generate_series()` to _create_ a Calendar table that can be used for date joining in future, or simply use a spreadsheet to generate information and export as a CSV to populate a Calendar table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` over an internal table to simulate `generate_series`.

```
date_gen AS ( 
    SELECT DATE_ADD('month', - i.i, DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)) AS mnth 
    FROM (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() i 
          FROM stl_scan 
          LIMIT 36
         ) i
)
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly :)
It's really great, I had read things like how row numbers could help. I'm going to dissect this function.